# Interactive PDF with added elements

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to figure out how to create a couple of PDFs where the basic idea is that there is a salesperson-side form and a customer-side handout. I'm wondering how to create a fillable PDF form that once the fields have been completely filled out by a salesperson and they hit something similar to a Submit button, that the information entered into the fields is then output into a summary format (perhaps into a separate file altogether?), and the new file would include marketing information, coupons and discounts, etc that could be given to a customer. Is this something that can be done?

Comment: This is feasible. How to implement depends on the actual documents. It will require a little bit of programming in Acrobat Javascript, but has been done.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a comment, the actual implementation depends on the project concerned.

A few approaches:

• The "output" pages could be part of the data entry document, and the information is simply passed to according fields in those pages; calculations and logic may be applied. The output pages may be visible, or they may be hidden Templates, which get spawned when the data entry is finished.

• The "output" pages are in their own document, and the data entry document opens it, and pushes relevent data to fill. The output document still may have some local intelligence.

Comment: I think either way might work, but the second bullet might work better (in this case). Are there any resources you can refer me to that would give some direction on how I could do this?

Comment: There is not really much floating around. What you will need in any case is the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the developer section of the Adobe website). The key point is to properly address the fields, meaning that you will have to get an understanding of the Acrobat/PDF object model.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **capture and process** form data in a PDF you need **[Adobe Livecycle](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle.html)**.

PDFs forms offer no inherent ability to actually process anything other than basic mouse events.

Without Livecycle, you might consider just an *intranet* web page for sales people to fill out an HTML form, which could then generate a PDF using server-side scripting.

Comment: I don't think they want to capture and process the data. They just want to recreate/output what was entered into the fields into a different format. Im not 100% sure if they know what they want, I just wanted to know if thats something that can be done with PDFs.

Comment: Uhm..."*...recreate/output what was entered into the fields...*" that **is** processing the entered data.

Comment: Yes I thought an HTML form would probably be what they would want, not PDF

Comment: Of course, one can overcomplicate things with server support, and – even worse – with XFA. And sometimes, it may be necessary. However, the scenario described in the OP have been implemented in PDF and are/were productively used.